# Error "This tag is too new, or too low activity, for Documentation to be created for it"

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was trying to **propose a new tag** ([Kundera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kundera)). I got an error:

> This tag is too new, or too low activity, for Documentation to be created for it.

The tag was created more than 4 years ago, so it qualifies for **too low activity**.

Does low activity mean fewer followers and few questions under the tag?

What are the criteria for a tag to be eligible for documentation?

Comment: What was the tag, by the way?

Comment: @JNat It's [kundera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kundera) another one is [apache drill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-drill)

Comment: I had the same trying to create a tag for SpecFlow

Comment: Just had the same for `ethereum` - please someone clarify on the criteria.

Comment: That may be a limitation of the Beta in order to work only with popular tags at the moment. Before opening it to more tags.

Comment: @A.L agree with the limitation. I just want to know the boundary values for becoming eligible for documentation.

Comment: Had the same with atg and oracle-commerce. My question is why stop people from creating documentation?

Comment: I agree. This is a chicken and egg issue. I have a large community that I currently support through a self-hosted Discourse forum and Gitter, meaning I have low traction on StackOverflow. This prevents me from evaluating the documentation feature as an alternative to my current setup.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue with [cakebuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakebuild) woudl love to know that the criteria is for acceptance.  We have a reasonably large community in Gitter, and seeing growing adoption of the tool, and would love to start using SO Documentation for helping grow our existing docs.

Comment: I've also noticed other fairly popular (but not super popular) tags not meeting the threshold. For example, `rx.net` shows the same message. This seems really limiting to me. In Q/A tags are mostly useful for searching and filtering. By using them as a barrier of entry for docs, it limits the docs to only those projects/tags with a lot of popularity. While that may be appropriate for searching/filtering Q/A it seems counter to what docs is intended to be. If I run a small OSS project and wanted to use the docs product to help document my tool, I can't right now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I emailed the Stack Overflow Team regarding this, and I got the following response:

> A tag does require at least 500 questions to have been asked with it before it can be proposed in the new Documentation beta. This restriction may change in the future, but that's the requirement for now. Keep in mind that this is a *beta* and the idea here is to get a grasp on how it's working with more popular languages before it expands into a full feature.

So the immediate criteria is for 500 questions to have been asked on a proposed tag.  Guess that rules out the tag I am interested in for now.

Comment: Either that, or *you'd better get busy asking questions*!

Comment: @CodyGray :-) for this particular tag, it would likely be me answering the questions, as one of the contributors to the project. We handle most of our questions through our Gitter Room, so very few questions on SO, but we were very interested in trying out the new Documentation offering.

Comment: From my point of view 500 is too much, a correct threshold would be around 200-300.  There exist some very specific tag, implying few documentation on internet, in this case allowing stackoverflow documentation would be a real advantage. To extrapolate, why allow  only  tags that have already lot of documentations on internet ?

Comment: Agree 500 questions seem very high, there should at least be some possibility to propose a tag and have a peer review option or similar.

Comment: Search for keyword -[keyword] ... that may get you to 500 questions more quickly