# Didn't gain reputation when the example I contributed was upvoted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, documentation

I contributed an edit to [that example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-arrays#t=201607220934017300921), but I don't gain reputation when that example is upvoted as help center said:

> example you contributed to is voted up: +5

Is that a bug? Or did I misunderstand the rules of documentation?

Comment: Are you asking *why* you gain reputation when an example you contributed to is upvoted, or reporting a bug that you *don't*?

Comment: reporting a bug that I don't. @CodyGray

Comment: There is a reputation cap. Have you hit it?

Comment: @CodyGray No. I gain 28 rep today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328703/1328704) explains:

> We are also raising the thresholds for what a "substantive edit" is.

Your edit didn't qualify as a "substantive edit," so you didn't get reputation for it.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't find the rule for qualifying `substantive edit` in that post. Could you please show me where can I find the rule?