# Mortarboard badge from Documentation reputation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, badges, daily-reputation-badges

Just curious - I participated in Documentation Beta, and now the rep that I'm getting since Documentation has been moved into Stack Overflow has exceeded 200 per day.

Does that rep count towards the [Mortarboard badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard)? It doesn't appear to, but I can't seem to find any documentation that clarifies.

Comment: Given that it's the same rep, it should. If it doesn't, that would be strange.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - That's what I would have guessed, but it clearly hasn't in my case....

Comment: Doc rep doesn't count toward the rep cap badges. Saw it discussed somewhere, but don't have a link. Sorry! Perhaps someone in the [docs chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta) can point you to the official response. (I'm hoping that won't change, or it will become too easy for people to earn Legendary.)

Comment: Yup, it doesn't count towards the badge, it's mentioned here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse#comment370137_328703

Answer (score 7):

No, the rep you get from documentation does not count to the Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary badges.

Why, I am not sure. I feel like there is an old west duel going on between the doc rep, and daily rep badges seeing who gets earned first.

Here is a link to the comments about it: [Addressing Documentation #RepGateApocalypse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse#comment370130_328703)

---

This has been changed. The rep from Docs.SO now count toward the Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary badges.