# 200 daily reputation count not updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, daily-reputation-limit

I know that [Documentation points do not count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329436/3681880) toward the [b](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard)a[d](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic)g[e](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary)s that are given for reaching the 200 daily rep limit. However, I have reached the limit with Q&A points alone several times recently but my counter has still been stuck at 29.

[image]

Let's take [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681880/suragch?tab=reputation) (August 8) as an example:

[image]

The red circled points are from documentation. Everything else is Q&A upvotes (no accept points).

```
point value     type
-----------------------------
15              documentation
225             Q&A
```

The Q&A points should have triggered the daily limit counter, but they didn't. A similar situation happened on August 3, 4, and 5. I didn't go back and check earlier than that, but I think it has been occurring since about the time that Documentation points started being given.

This looks like a bug to me.

**Update**

- On August 15 I reached the daily limit *without* any Documentation points and the counter *was* updated.
- On August 16 I reached the daily limit *with* Documentation points and the counter was *not* updated (even though Q&A points were enough).

This confirms that it is related to the Documentation points.

Comment: Have you been getting exactly 200 rep worth of upvotes these days? Including some accepts? The +15 from accepts don't stop at the cap IIRC so they may not count for your daily rep count either

Comment: @TylerH, None of my points are from accepts in the last 2 weeks. I hardly ever answer new questions so I don't get accept points very often.

Comment: I think I've also run into this. I ran into the rep cap (I got upvotes but didn't get points for them), but didn't get a new day counted towards Epic.

Comment: @TylerH, the +15 from accepts don't count towards the +200 limit (nor do bounty points). However, they both count towards the badges obtained for getting 200, or more, points in a single day (from all sources, except documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation rep events weren't being counted for those badges, since the whitelist of counted events hadn't been updated.  There's a whitelist because certain events don't count, mostly those that remove reputation.

Badges will start catching up with the latest deploy (they're awarded on a schedule on the backend, so it'll take a day or so).

Comment: The count was updated and the problem fixed. Thanks for the explanation, too.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a bug to me.  My understanding of how the system works is that as votes come in the are applied to the rep cap.  Once the cap is hit the only new rep you will get is from non-capped rep like bounties and accepts.  If this is the way it works then the script will see docs rep and not give you the badge

I propose that all non-docs rep should be applied to the cap and only docs rep be used to fill in the gap if the regular rep does not reach the cap.  If your non-docs rep makes you hit the cap you should still get the badge. This makes it a little more complicated but I also believe more fair.

Comment: I think Docs rep should count toward the badge/cap since it's part of Q&A rep.

Comment: @TylerH I have no stance on that.  If it did then this would be moot.  Since it does not(at least not right now) I can only conclude it is a bug right now in the way rep is applied to the cap.

Comment: it seemed you were saying docs rep should not--by default--apply toward the rep cap.

Comment: @TylerH Yes.  Docs rep should not count unless you do not have enough regular rep to make it.  Ih you get 250 regular rep and 250 docs rep the system should only use 200 regular rep(assuming no non capped rep) and you get the badge.  If you had 50 regular rep and 250 docs rep the the system should make it 50 regular and 150 docs and you do not get the badge.

Comment: why do you think the system should keep two separate running tallies of rep? If you get 200 rep, you should hit the cap and earn the badge. Whether it's all from Docs, all from Q&A, half and half, or some other combination.

Comment: @TylerH I only think this because SO explicitly decided not to let docs rep apply to the badges.  If they change that stance then it would be fine.  If they do not then you should still get that badge if you get enough non docs rep.

Comment: I see, so you're just saying "assuming the system stays the way it is"

Comment: Yes.  SO so far does not seem to want to include docs rep in the badge.  If it stays that way then this needs to be fixed.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's odd for Docs rep to be "normal" rep on SO, but not count towards the rep badges. If I had a vote, I'd make it all the same.

Comment: @NateBarbettini, I expect that docs rep will eventually count towards those badges. My assumption has been that while docs is in beta they are thinking the total rep provided may change. If/When it does change, all rep from docs will be recalculated. If people were getting badges for the rep now, then when the re-calc occurs, the badges would have to be removed if the user no longer qualifies. It is simpler to just do a final? rep-recalc and apply any badges then to have to remember when/how a badge was obtained and remove the badge from the user when they no longer qualify due to the re-calc.