# Was there a Documentation post-mortem?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In the post on [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/734069), it was stated:

> We also plan to write a retrospective on the blog and make this a topic of an [upcoming Town Hall Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298165/lets-do-regular-meta-se-town-hall-chats-next-event-july-26-2017). I’m planning a few posts for my personal blog as well.

It's been half a year since the Documentation beta terminated. Have any of these things happened? I searched the Blog website for "Documentation", but I only got stuff pre-sunset. If there was a chat, does anyone have a link to the chat-log?

Comment: There definitely was a chat, but I don't recall which room it was in - probably on MSE.  What I _do_ remember of that chat...not much really?  Sounded like what we had already talked about on MSO before it shut down.

Comment: I would be interested in reading such a post, if it existed.

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-5-9-august-2017 and this was the documentation rescue room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/153924/2017/9/8

Comment: There'll be a new chat room in 6-8 weeks

Comment: I'm 99.999% certain I heard Jon talking about writing one a bunch of times. Whether or not he actually _did it_ remains to be discovered, pinging him about this now :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I never did write that retrospective. (Though I did touch on Documentation in [my 2017 retrospective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/31/stack-exchange-2017-review/) and [my personal blog](http://jericson.github.io/2017/12/08/race_to_1k_5.html).) We also used [100% of Town Hall #5](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/town-hall-5-9-august-2017) to talk docs. Last summer our UX researcher intern, Horyun Song, interviewed 13 technical writers and wrote up [her results](http://horyun.design/docs) on her website. She did a more thorough and expert job than I did, but since you asked:

## Why Documentation didn't work

There's a great book by Donald Norman called [*The Design of Everyday Things*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Design_of_Everyday_Things) (*DOET*) which centers on the concept of [affordance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance). An example (not from the book) is the modern phone screen that *affords* touching. My 5-year-olds expect screens to respond when touched, which is why the bottom few inches of the living room TV are covered in fingerprints. Older generations struggle to use touch screens because years of reinforcement have taught us that touching screens only results in smudges. (That said, I sometimes find myself touching words on physical books in hopes that the definition will appear as on my Kindle.)

We knew going into Documentation that people don't much like writing it. It tends to be boring material, it requires subject knowledge *and* understanding of the target audience, feedback (if you ever get it) is often negative, and the task lacks the glamor of development. So much of our work was aimed at creating good affordances for writing:

- Anyone could propose changes and the barriers for approving them were low.
- During the private beta, the default tag view was geared toward authors, not consumers.
- Integrating the existing reputation system into Documentation was a primary design goal.
- Far more work was put into the editor (which used [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/)) than in organization. (Most egregiously, I proposed [hierarchy would arise organically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328351/1438).)

And, in fact, we did get lots of contributions both during the private beta, [at launch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th) and each time we announced a new set of changes. Unfortunately, activity died off after a short while and we never had the sort of engagement we hoped for. Meanwhile, we made a few missteps at launch (notably, [#RepGateApocalypse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse)) that soured the community on the project. At some point, I noticed I was [getting a handful of downvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/849217/how-many-downvotes-do-i-get-per-tag?user=1438) whenever I posted anything on meta about Documentation. People [loved the concept](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), but not the execution.

Horyun [makes a wonderful analogy](http://horyun.design/docs) involving chairs. Imagine walking into a room with these two setups:

[image: Chaos vs. Organization]

The right hand side is clearly more welcoming since the chairs are arraigned in a way that welcomes (*affords*) sitting. Without clear organization, Documentation started to look a lot more like the the chairs on the left. Private beta users saw a clean slate and users at launch walked into a work in progress. Some topics were better organized than others, but our focus on content creation distracted from content curation.

Even so, I believe we were headed toward success. If you remember when touch screens first hit the market, they didn't work so well. They didn't always register interactions and the underlying paradigm was the mouse pointer. It took years of [iteration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation) in both hardware and software to get something that felt right. Stack Overflow has changed the way people relate to documentation making it [easier to search the long-tail](http://jericson.github.io/2016/08/25/long_tail_docs.html). Typing a question into Google will show you both results from official documentation and practical examples from Stack Overflow. More and more projects are opening up their documentation for public contributions.

Ultimately, it was resource allocation that ended Documentation. In the best scenario, the connection between the Documentation project and revenue was tenuous. Assuming we brought in new contributors (we did, but not as many as we hoped) and assuming they created a Developer Story, it might help us [sell our hiring tools](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent) to new customers. Meanwhile, we had begun [a project that offered more immediate returns](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) and will likely require far less iteration.

It might not be immediately obvious, but Documentation has changed how Stack Overflow Inc. operates. As you might gather, we didn't do a lot of user research upfront, but by the end of the project [user interviews](http://jericson.github.io/2016/06/30/usability_tests.html) directed our development process. Not only were we looking at meta feedback, which happens only when some aspect of the experience is particularly frustrating, but also at the more subtle cues when people start interacting with the site. A couple of weeks ago, I sat in on some interviews [Donna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4406529/donna?tab=profile) conducted with Teams beta users. We discovered things that changed the development process and makes the experience better for all users.

Personally, I will always be grateful for my experience on Documentation. For the first time in my career as a Community Manager, I was part of an integrated development team. Along with the Product Manager, I triaged community feedback, answered meta questions and planned update announcements. Along with the developers and designers, I proposed and tested changes to the system. And I reported progress to the rest of the community team in our weekly meeting. Stack Overflow is *community software*. It can't be developed outside the context of the people who make it run. Working (and often failing) to listen to our users helped me grow into this job.

Comment: On a matter you sort-of touched on, when are we getting CommonMark support across SE sites?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Not soon enough, I'm afraid. :-(

Comment: It seems strange to hear such positivity around Documentation in this. As a moderately-active user, I never saw or read anything positive about documentation. Upon going there it didn't seem useful, and seemingly the entire meta community was up in arms about repgate. This post waxes aspirational about where Documentation would have gone, but doesn't describe why that was assumed. It says little user research was done at the outset, so why all the perseverance on a project that so many actively disliked? I don't mean to be harsh, but that's the big question I'm interested in from a postmortem.

Comment: @Knetic From my reading, and my experience contributing to Docs, it was a great idea! ... But poorly executed, which is part of why more and more people started to hate it. I loved the concept and idea! By the end, however, I too was hating the actual system. As far as I know, I was one of the last few to turn from "This is great!" to "This is pretty terrible..." It also doesn't help that at the start, a lot of us weren't clear what Docs would be for or what hole they would fill. So a number of meta users went in prepared to hate the system because it _felt_ poorly planned.

Comment: @Knetic: Once we started doing user research with people actually participating on the system, we discovered both the annoyances and the accomplishments. Some tags (I'm thinking of C, but there were others) had a lot of excellent topics and committed users. [Horyun's research](http://horyun.design/docs) helped us see what we'd been doing wrong _and_ gave us a clear direction to fix problems. The long and short of it: meta is fickle and our focus on creation rather than use didn't help people see the promise we saw.

Comment: @Kendra: It was never a great idea. "A single place for all documentation", now that's something that might be of use, but that is **not** an idea - it's the starting point for an idea, as it doesn't contain any definition of what "documentation" means. The *idea* for SO Documentation was a single place to have  **lots of short examples**, and that itself is just an awful idea. The execution is not to blame because it was executed exactly to design. It's the initial concept, idea and design that was flawed from that start, and every post I read about it is just trying to cover up a mistake

Comment: @Knetic: Well said. It unsettles me to know that the powers that be thought it would work, or even tried to convince us 'regular folk' of the good in it when we could all see it was never going to work. I also would like to see some explanation of why anyone thought it was going to be successful. Because at the moment it seems like something that was though up as an answer to the question "how can we make more money?". Because I really struggle to see any possible way this idea could have come from the question "how can we make something useful for the community?".