# Could Stack Overflow Documentation be revived as a part of of Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, stack-overflow-for-teams

Stack Overflow Documentation never made much sense as an attempt to somehow replace or supplement, in a centralized way, existing documentation for various languages, tools, or open source projects.  Those things all had their own documentation - granted, of varying qualities - and Stack Overflow Documentation inevitably wound up competing with their own documentation projects for limited energy.

But there's a potential place for it -- potentially an incredibly valuable place for it -- as a part of Stack Overflow for Teams.  As a tool to allow private companies and projects to write and manage their own documentation, it could be really valuable.

Right now it doesn't seem like there's one single great way to manage private code and process documentation.  There are products like [Atlassian Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence), but Atlassian's stuff is very hit or miss in my experience.  There are documentation generators like [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), but then you're stuck writing your documentation in markdown effectively.  And you have to find some way to host that documentation privately.

Seems like adding Stack Overflow Documentation to Stack Overflow for Teams could provide real value and help teams write and organize internal code documentation. The two combined - Documentation for organizing process docs, one pagers, or long form high level code docs and Q&A for, well, Q&A - could cover all the bases really well.  Is there any possibility of this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think adding Documentation to Teams would be a really great combination. Maintaining good documentation (either technical or procedural) has been a near-impossible challenge on every team I've been a part of. So far [Teams has come the closest](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/23/how-stack-overflow-for-teams-fits-into-the-community/) to solving the problem, but it would be nice to have a system that doesn't require me to ask a fake question in order to write documentation. (This, in fact, is what I'm doing in another tab. It's irritating.)

That said, [our Documentation product had structural problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367572/1438). Fixing those problems requires considerable effort which [we couldn't afford in 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation). The Teams development team is in the discovery stage for new features to add to the product. It's not out of the realm of possibility that we could develop Documentation for Teams. (This is entirely speculative, but I could see this as a "premium" addon feature for teams willing to spend a little more.) My guess, however, is that any Documentation product we create in the future will share nothing with the previous feature but the name (as is the [tradition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams)).

Answer (score 16):

Part of the problem with Documentation was that it really wasn't formatted well for documentation-  it was too heavily leveraging the Q&A code.  It was really only any good for collections of examples.  Quite frankly I don't think it has a fraction of the capabilities I want in a documentation source.  You're better off standing up a wiki server, or using a hosted wiki solution.  Of which there's dozens, if not hundreds.  Including big names like Microsoft, Atlassian, and small names like Notion.