# Lets make Stack Overflow Documentation rise again?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, reputation

I recently heard that before I was here, there was a place called [stackoverflow.com/documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation). However, it was sun downed, and one of the reasons why was because not enough new users contributed.

Here is my proposal:

We bring it back, and do the following(these are off the top of my head):

1. Your edits are binding **only and only if** you have above 2,000 reputation(the exact number can be decided on later).
2. You can only edit documentation in the languages for which you have at least two accepted answers **and** at least 3 scores for.
3. Before you have 2,000 reputation, you have to get your contributions **approved** by trusted users. It would work similarly to the edit-approve system. I would suggest a reputation gain of 5, maybe even 10!

Any other suggestions?

Comment: i am against it, but should it nit be atleast a bronze medal for teh language, two answers is definitly to low for a cntribution

Comment: @nbk Yes, now that I think of it, that makes a little more sense.

Comment: " one of the reasons why was because not enough new users contributed." - so your proposal is *to limit* number of participants because you said it was not enough participants... I'm totally confused how one solves the other.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am not saying limit the number of users who can edit documentation. I am saying reward users if they edit. This should encourage more users to contribute.

Comment: @TheMaker documnst was closed, because the get out of hand, because even experts differ in opinion and get confrontative about some aspects , if you had said a tutorial, where you can get cuttimg edge and accurate and safe tutorials, i would agree such a thing sis needed

Comment: @nbk If I understand you corrrectly, you're saying documentation might become like wikipedia, in which case I agree with you.

Comment: @TheMaker for me it was worse. Imagine Wikipedia launched a side-project called WikiDefinitionArticles. This side project contains articles written by the community on certain topics. So, now if you want to look something up, you have to check both Wikipedia *and* WikiDefinitionArticles to find an answer. It's how documentation felt. The information wasn't just scattered but scattered *even worse*. On SO the search isn't great but at least you search one place. In Documentation you could find the information you needed under an unexpected heading.

Comment: @VLAZ Ya, I wasn't there, and I think you were, so I understand what you are saying.

Comment: \*[Let's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let%27s#Etymology)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm excited people are interested in Documentation. It has the potential to make Stack Overflow even more useful for even more people. That said, it's [a lot more complicated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367572/1438) than anyone thought. Not only do you need to create a system that's easy to read and understand, you need to create a system that people will be excited about contributing to.

Have you ever had a Wiki at work that people are supposed to edit? In my experience they either get like three contributions and never get used again or someone uses it for their personal scratchpad and nobody else looks at it. (I may or may not have been that guy.) Wikipedia makes this look easy, but I assure you it isn't. Getting the right system in place requires the right people leading the effort. People who care deeply about the end result before worrying about how they will personally benefit.

I've come to believe that Stack Overflow is *good enough* documentation. When other sources (especially the official documentation) are unclear, incomplete or wrong, someone will ask a question on Stack Overflow that someone else can answer. And when yet another person has that same question, there's a chance they will find their answer on Stack Overflow via Google. If you are the sit-in-a-comfy-chair-with-a-beverage-reading-the-manual type of person, that might not be very satisfying. But for the average person, [it works](https://jlericson.com/2016/08/25/long_tail_docs.html).

Therefore, the bar to clear is slightly higher: can Stack Overflow Documentation exceed the usefulness of Stack Overflow Q&A? If I had to guess, the way such a feature could be developed would be if there was a demand for it from Enterprise and Teams customers. That would also be a decent laboratory for such an experiment.

Comment: Yes, I seem to understand what you are saying.

Comment: I'm glad you've come to see it my way, @Jon. :-) As I said years ago, I think self-answered canonical questions are a *criminally* underused feature and provide a very useful and important way to get this high-quality, curated documentation onto SO itself.

Comment: Another factor here: services like https://readthedocs.org/ (not to mention less specialized services such as GitHub's wikis and countless CMSs) haven't stood still over the past couple of years. As you say, the bar was already high when Docs was in active development; it's higher now.